# How to create unit test for ActualWidth in Silverlight 4?

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit, actualwidth

How can I write a unit test to test the `ActualWidth` property in a `UserControl` in Silverligh 4?

I hoped that this method would pass, but it fails.

I am using the Silverlight ToolKit april 2010, and VS 2010.

```
<TestMethod()> _
Public Sub TestAcrtualWidth()
    Me.MyUserControl.Width = 100
    Me.MyUserControl.UpdateLayout()
    Assert.IsTrue(Me.MyUserControl.ActualWidth > 0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I added MyUserControl to a new instance of a `Canvas`.
If I instead used :

```
Me.TestPanel.Children.add(Me.MyUserControl)
```

It worked!